# Wordpress Login doesnt respond after using Filezilla to upload my files on the server

Tags: filesystem

Last week, the most recent update of Wordpress 5.3 came out and I updated it. As many other people, my website had a lot of problems after the update, due to the fact that my plugins such as openwp didnt work properly with it.

I was able to fix after a while, to be able to access my Wordpress Dashboard again.

But I needed to use Filezilla, because I wanted to change my URL. I made an update with updraftplus right before I installed the newest Wordpress version. I saved it on my computer and downloaded Filezilla client.

I extracted the file and uploaded them on the server.

Everything went through smoohtly, but as soon as I finished, I wasnt able to open my website anymore. Ever since then, I have not been able to reach my Wordpress backend and my actual Website doesnt show up on my URL.

I know that my data is not gone, because I can see it on the server, but I am wondering if I overwrote files, or did something wrong. I dont really want to try anything else out anymore, because I am scared of making it worse. Also I cannot find any information on that online.

Furthermore my Wpcontent index says (Silent is golden) and I was like that after I downloaded the files onto my computer.

I really dont know what to do now.

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Rene it will be difficult to say without even looking at the website, maybe file permissions were changed when you uploaded or edited files and server can no longer access them? Can you send me a link?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! 

This is the URL I initially used: www.vermietungswelt.zass-hosting.de

Comment: This is the URL I want uploaded the data on through FileZilla!  www.vermietungswelt.de

Answer (score 1):

Check the wp-config.php file on your site. It should contain the database credentials (db name, user, password) for your site. Verify those values. Maybe even change the password via your hosting control panel (MySQL Databases) for the user for that database.

Then check the error.log file in the root of your site, and in the wp-admin folder. That might help out.

There are other things to check out; this guide should help you get started. https://wordpress.org/support/category/troubleshooting/

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! This helps out a lot! I will keep you updated what has worked for me! Or if it still doesn’t work!